# SQL command to select library shelf containing only books of a given color

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a library (table library). In that library many shelves (column shelf). On those shelves can be books with different colors (column color).

The task: return the numbers of the shelves where stays only red books.

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (1, '2', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (2, '2', 'white');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (3, '3', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (4, '4', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (5, '4', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (6, '2', 'blue');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (7, '4', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (8, '3', 'green');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (9, '1', 'blue');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (10, '1', 'blue');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (11, '5', 'green');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (12, '5', 'black');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (13, '6', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (14, '6', 'red');
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `shelf`, `color`) VALUES (15, '6', 'white');
```

In the case above, it should return only shelf number 4.

Comment: Is this homework?(if yes, tag it as homework). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT shelf FROM test
GROUP BY shelf
HAVING COUNT(IF(color = 'red', 1, NULL)) = COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Seems to be truth) You're Genius)

Comment: @Devart: `COUNT(*) > 0` is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: @ypercube oops, I thought I need it. Removed. Thanks ;-)

Comment: +1 just learned something new

Answer (score 1):

This one will work:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct shelf from test where color='red') f;
```

The inner query (select distinct shelf from test where color='red') will return distinct shelves numbers which contain red books:

```
2
3
4
6
```

Then we search the count of those shelves (4)

Comment: I think he wants the value of the `shelf` field rather than the count of shelves. It's unfortunate that his example data set makes that even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Only red shelves

```
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (1, '2', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (2, '2', 'white'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (3, '3', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (4, '4', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (5, '4', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (6, '2', 'blue'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (7, '4', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (8, '3', 'green'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (9, '1', 'blue'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (10, '1', 'blue'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (11, '5', 'green'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (12, '5', 'black'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (13, '6', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (14, '6', 'red'); 
INSERT INTO test (id, shelf, color) VALUES (15, '6', 'white');

SELECT shelf 
FROM test 
WHERE color = 'red'
-- Uncomment the group by if you want a grouped result set    
--GROUP BY shelf;

SELECT shelf, count(shelf)
FROM test 
WHERE color = 'red'
GROUP BY shelf;

SELECT count(shelf)
FROM test 
WHERE color = 'red'
```

Comment: No, you probably didn't get what task is. We need shelves where ONLY red book. Foe example, on shelf 2 laid red, white and blue book. We don't need this shelf.

Comment: This doesn't seem to acknowledge what I think is a key part of the admittedly vague question. He seems to want to return a shelf which contains nothing other than red books. Your query would also return shelf 3, but that does also contain a green book.

Comment: YES! Nothing other red books! Right!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, did'nt get what you wanted at first. This will work better.

```
select distinct t1.shelf from  test t1 
where t1.color='red' and not 
  exists (select shelf from test where shelf=t1.shelf and color != 'red')
```

We search shelves which have red books on them and don't have not red books in them (the exists sub-query)